# Check CPU utilization of rsync and kill if it crosses a threshold

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I have a shell script running four rsync commands sequentially. This script is scheduled to run every 20 min using a CRON job.
Sometimes the rsync process takes upto 30% CPU utilization, slowing the server down. This is causing problems.

This is my script:

```
### rsync_script.sh

#!/bin/bash

rsync -avz --delete --bwlimit=5000 /path1/to/file/filename_* root@1.1.1.1:/destination/path1/

rsync -avz --delete --bwlimit=5000 /path2/to/file/filename_* root@1.1.1.1:/destination/path2/

rsync -avz --delete --bwlimit=5000 /path3/to/file/filename_* root@1.1.1.1:/destination/path3/

rsync -avz --delete --bwlimit=5000 /path4/to/file/filename_* root@1.1.1.1:/destination/path4/
```

I run the cron job:

```
*/20 * * * * /bin/sh  /path/to/script/rsync_script.sh
```

I need to put a check such that if the CPU utilization of rsync exceeeds say 5%, then I need to stop the script.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Killing off an rsync session midway through wouldn't be recommended due to issues with data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If using too much CPU is your issue, then rather than killing the process, you might schedule it at a lower priority.

See `man 1 nice` for instructions on a tool to do that.

The `-z` option you are using is a compression option - if you are CPU constrained that might be something to tweak and test.

The `--stats` option gives you a sense for rsync's internal statistics on efficiency, also something good to look at while tuning things.

Good luck - fortunately there are some things you can tune.